# How do I get IDs associated with the most frequent value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by, count

I have following data in my PostgreSQL 11 database `count_tbl` (Windows 10 x64 machine).

```
grp     id     value
1       1      19.7
1       2      19.7
1       3      19.7
1       4      19.7
1       5      19.7
1       6      19.7
1       7      18.8
1       8      18.8
1       9      18.8
1       10     18.8
1       11     18.8
1       12     18.8
2       1      18.6
2       2      18.6
2       3      18.6
2       4      18.6
2       5      18.6
2       6      0.0
2       7      0.0
2       8      0.0
2       9      21.4
2       10     21.4
2       11     0.0
2       12     0.0
```

The following query, for each group (`grp`), finds the most frequent value:

```
Select Distinct on (grp)
    grp,
    case
        when freq > 1
        then value
        else 0.0
    end as freq_val
From
(
    Select
        grp,
        value,
        count(id) as freq
    From count_tbl
    Group by grp, value
    Order by grp
) s1
Order by grp, freq desc, value desc;
```

The output of above query is:

```
grp    freq_val
1      19.7
2      18.6
```

Now, I would like to associate the most frequent value to the corresponding IDs (for example, for `grp = 1`, most frequent value `19.7` have ids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), let say, as an `integer array`. My expected output is:

```
grp    freq_val     ids
1      19.7         {1,2,3,4,5,6}
2      18.6         {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Does someone care to reflect on this or suggest how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select
    grp,
    value freq_val,
    array_agg(id) ids
from (
    select
        c.*,
        rank() over(partition by grp order by value desc) rn
    from count_tbl
) t
where rn = 1
group by grp, value
```

The inner query ranks records having the same `grp` by decreasing `value`. Then, the outer query filter on the top rows per froup and aggregates.

---

Edit: if you want the most occuring value per group (instead of the highest value) and its associated ids, then you can aggregate in the subquery instead:

```
select *
from (
    select
        grp,
        value freq_val,
        array_agg(id) ids
        rank() over(partition by grp order by count(*) desc) rn
    from count_tbl
    group by grp, value
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort! I tested your code.. Here is output: **1, 19.7, {1,2,3,4,5,6}** and **2, 21.4, {9,10}**. For group 2, the most frequent value is **21.4** which isn't true if we look at the sample data Hope it makes sense? :)

Comment: I think, your code finds the highest value instead of the most repeating or common value. Clearly, 19.7 and 21.4 are the highest values as given in your code output.

Comment: @khajlk: I see your point. I updated my answer with another query.

Comment: The output of above query was repeating IDs because equal number of IDs can hold same value: **1,19.7, {1,2,3,4,5,6}, 1, 18.8,{7,8,9,10,11,12}** and **2, 0.0, {6,7,8,11,12}, 2, 18.6, {1,2,3,4,5}**. I added 'Distinct on (grp)' and 'Order by grp, value desc' and I got the expected output. Care to update your second code? and I am happy to accept the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`.  This is fun because it does not require a subquery:

```
select distinct on (grp) grp, value, count(*) as freq,
       array_agg(id) over (partition by grp) as ids
from count_tbl
group by grp, value
order by gp, count(*) desc, value desc;
```

Most databases require a subquery, either to use a window function or some other comparison.  `DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension.

Comment: Hello, two things: (1) maybe I was unable to make myself clear in the question..because I don't only need the frequent value. I also need to associate the freq value to corresponding ids. (2) Your code gives the output: **1, 19.7, 6** and **2, 0.0, 5**, which is different my first output .Your code just gives the most frequent value, in group 2, values 18.6 and 0.0 have equal counts (i.e., 5), my query selects 18.6 as most freq value which i think makes more sense..

Comment: @khajlk . . . If you want a tie breaker, just add another key to the `order by`.  I added `value desc` to get the larger value in the event of a tie.

Comment: Still, the arrray values are like this **{7,8,4,1,9,3,2,6,10,12,11,5}** and **{1,4,7,2,6,12,5,3,9,8,10,11}** for group 1 and 2 :(